# EPC bit direction in Tag Data

Tags: rfid

When I call the TagData.getTagID () function

(https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-15/apis/reference/com/zebra/rfid/api3/TagData.html#getTagID)

It return String: `330DB3D31270016101000001` (EPC)

Binary is:

```
001100110000110110110011110100110001001001110000000000010110000100000001000000000000000000000001
```

As far as I know the EPC is from bit 20h to 7Fh

I want to ask about the sequence of bits in the EPC in the code above

```
20h     ->      7Fh

001100110000110110110011110100110001001001110000000000010110000100000001000000000000000000000001
```

or is :

```
7Fh    <-     20h

001100110000110110110011110100110001001001110000000000010110000100000001000000000000000000000001
```

Which direction is the correct sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the EPC in the EPC memory bank is stored from 20h until ...h (depending on the length of the EPC). A typical RFID reader doesn't include the full EPC Memory Bank in the 'EPC' data field, just the 'EPC' itself. So, there is no need to any further processing to the hexadecimal content you got, it is actually the EPC itself.

If you put it in an EPC translator tool (like https://www.mimasu.nl/tag-encoding/tdt), you can see it produces the GRAI 04569951110054141750697985.